# How can I filter users in django to many to many fields?

Tags: python, sql, django

HERE IS MY MODEL:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="students")
    crated_at = models.DateField(auto_created=True)
```

How can I check request user in students?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for filtering :-

```
user_filter = Course.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```